# Could not load file or assembly 'Sitecore.Analytics' or one of its dependencies

Tags: sitecore

I am facing one error while login into sitecore.

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'Sitecore.Analytics' or one of its dependencies"
```

Even if I exclude `sitecore.analitics.config` from incude folder. But still I am facing this issue.

Comment: Please add more details on this issue, like which version of sitecore, do you have Sitecore.Analytics dll installed in your bin folder, and the complete error stack.

Comment: This is fresh setup or pre-existing ? If pre-existing, have u recently installed any module / package ?

Answer (score 6):

You **must** have the `Sitecore.Analytics.dll` file in your `/bin` folder, even if you are not using DMS.
If you are missing the file completely then you should re-download the Sitecore files for your version from [SDN](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Resources/Sitecore%207/Sitecore%20CMS.aspx) and add the missing file to your application.

Comment: Ruud is right. Sitecore.Analytics.dll is part of any (recent) Sitecore distribution and must be present in /bin regardless of whether Sitecore Analytics is being used/enabled or not

Answer (score 4):

You can also try to exclude the Sitecore.Analytics.Robots.config as well

This error means your /bin/ does not contain Sitecore.Analytics.dll

Answer (score 0):

I would also check to make sure there is nothing in your web.config file (or various include files) that is targeting a specific version of the Analytics.dll

Answer (score 0):

Please exclude these files from app_config/include folder and then retry

```
Sitecore.Analytics.config
Sitecore.Analytics.ExcludeRobots.config
Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.config
```